# Have a function similar to float8in_internal_null( ) for Integer types?

Tags: c, postgresql, apache-age

I am currently developing a function that converts a list of values to integers. In the case of float types, we have the convenient `float8in_internal_null()` function at `toFloatList()`, which returns the appropriate float value if the conversion is successful, but returns **NULL** if the conversion of a list element fails.

However, when working with integers and using the `atoi()` function, I encountered a limitation. Unlike `float8in_internal_null()`, `atoi()` does not return **NULL** when it fails to convert an element of the list to an integer. Instead, it returns 0.

Is there an alternative function within some library in **AGE**, that can help me achieve the desired behavior of returning **NULL** when a conversion to an integer is not possible? I would appreciate any guidance on this matter.

Comment: In which language are you developing this function? Please select _one_.

Comment: C or C++? In C a function can only return one type so I assume this can't be C. As far as I recall the same goes for C++ but I haven't done C++ for a while so perhaps I don't remember that correctly. Anyway, in C I would take a look at `strtoul`. With a few extra checks it seems  you can (nearly) reach your goal.

Comment: `NULL` is not a valid value for `float` in C, and `nullptr` is not a valid value for `float` in C++ either. I.e. the premise of the question is already flawed. However, most C implementations do support `NaN` (not-a-number), which is somewhat similar. On the flip side, hardly any C implementation supports `NaN` for `int` types.

Comment: Also, pick a language. In C++ a failure to convert would cause a `std::runtime_error` exception, possibly a `std::range_error`. See also `std::stoi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use check if the string you need to convert is zero, if it's not zero and atoi() returns 0, then the string cannot be converted to an integer. Therefore, you can return or pass NULL.

```
int result = atoi(string);
if (strcmp(string, "0") != 0 && result == 0)
{
    return NULL;
}
```

Additionally, if you want you can use the function `age_tointeger` from AGE, calling  this function inside your C function using `DirectFunctionCall`.

EDIT:
We should then utilize `strtoi64(string, &errorOK, 10)` from Postgres to convert a regular integer string, this function handles errors like invalid syntax and out of range integer.

Comment: You had better recommend `strtol`, which has ways to report an error.

Comment: Other strings for which `atoi` correctly returns zero are `+0`, `-0`, `00`, and `0foo` (because `atoi` is specified to convert the initial portion of the string), so the test in this routine is inadequate. Additionally, while OP may have observed `atoi` returning zero on error, this is not necessarily always so, as the C standard does not specify it, and so it should not be relied upon. When there is an overflow, the routine is likely to return some non-zero value.

Answer (score 0):

In C or C++, there is no special value like null or None like other languages. NULL in C-C++ is just a macro that defines it as 0. So, unlike other languages, C-C++ functions return 0. You need to add an additional check to verify if the case is an error or if 0 is the right answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int i = atoi(num);
    if (num!="0" && i == 0)
    {
        cout<<"Error"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Instead, if you can use C++ libraries, you can also use `std::stoi`. It raises an exception in such cases, which can be handled.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to return `NULL` as a string and also return as an `int` in the same function. `NULL` is a macro which is equivalent to 0 if you return `NULL` as an int you get `0` which defeats the purpose of your intended functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no built in function for integers like `float8in_internal_null()` that will return `NULL` in case of conversion failure.
You have to implement your own function to achieve this result.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function ( Suggested name: **int4in_internal_null()** ) for integers.

You need to write custom logic to tackle this problem.

OR

Use the **COALESCE()** function from SQL.

OR

Create a new issue on this [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/age/issues) for feature suggestion.